# iPhone Storyboard with a loop behaviour

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller, reusability, avcapturesession

I have a series of ViewControllers in a storyboard. Now some transitions loop back to previous ViewControllers.

My question is:

- What kind of issues can this cause?
- What effect does this have on the ViewController live cycle? On another pass through the ViewController, is it created again or is it reused?
- What is a better way to do this?

(I'm asking this because an AVCaptureSession I'm using works fine on the first pass through but has some issues (with resuming from interruption) on subsequent passes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each segue in a storyboard to a view controller creates a new instance of that view controller. When your storyboard has segue cycles, you're cycling through new instances of the view controllers, not repeated uses.